# SQL Join on two columns where equal on 1 and Not equal on the other

Tags: sql, linq-to-entities

How can I join 2 different tables on 2 columns where one column is equal and the other is not. In the example below, I need to query for records where the email matches but the NID does not.

```
Table A
ID              NID                  Email
1               bob                  bob@asdf.com
2               mike                 mike@asdf.com
3               dave                 dave@asdf.com

Table B
ID              NID                  Email
1               bob                  bob@asdf.com
2               mike                 mike@asdf.com
3               doug                 dave@asdf.com
```

Sample output should be from Table B:

```
ID              NID                  Email

3               doug                 dave@asdf.com
```

Bonus points if you can do it in LINQ to Entities

Comment: Sample data doesnt match what you want?  Also the question is poorly worded.  Show us correct sample data, what field matches or is used to join as both tables ahve the same fields (what is the key here).  Sample of resultant row.

Comment: your question still doesn't make a lot of sense even after your edit.  How do you want to link these tables, what is the point of what you are trying to do.  Do you want an `OR` condition within your JOIN so you can test a join for email OR id?

Comment: @JonH: I have reworded it again. HTH

Comment: Are downvotes magnetic or is my questions still unclear?

Comment: Well you cant blame the downvoters, your question was poorly worded, spend the time to ask a good solid question with a lot of nice details and you can expect a solid answer.  Check my answer below.

Comment: 3 downvotes came in the questions current state, which I can't make any clearer.

Comment: well your question is answered why don't you use it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #TableA
(
    ID int,
    NID varchar(25),
    Email varchar(50)
)

CREATE TABLE #TableB
(
    ID int,
    NID varchar(25),
    Email varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO #TableA(ID, NID, Email) VALUES (1, 'bob', 'bob@asdf.com')
INSERT INTO #TableA(ID, NID, Email) VALUES (2, 'mike', 'mike@asdf.com')
INSERT INTO #TableA(ID, NID, Email) VALUES (3, 'dave', 'dave@asdf.com')

INSERT INTO #TableB(ID, NID, Email) VALUES (1, 'bob', 'bob@asdf.com')
INSERT INTO #TableB(ID, NID, Email) VALUES (2, 'mike', 'mike@asdf.com')
INSERT INTO #TableB(ID, NID, Email) VALUES (3, 'doug', 'dave@asdf.com')

SELECT 
    #TableB.ID, 
    #TableB.NID, 
    #TableB.Email
FROM 
    #TableB Inner Join #TableA
    ON #TableA.ID = #TableB.ID WHERE #TableA.NID <> #TableB.NID

DROP TABLE #TableA
DROP TABLE #TableB
```

---

Result:

3 doug dave@asdf.com

---

In conclusion just a join with a WHERE condition

```
SELECT 
    TableB.ID, 
        TableB.NID, 
        TableB.Email
FROM 
        TableB 
Inner Join 
        TableA
ON TableA.ID = TableB.ID WHERE TableA.NID <> TableB.NID
```

Comment: Your query works well and is what I was looking for. Not sure why I couldn't come up with this on my own. Thanks for all your help in clarifying my question and ultimately answering it.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA JOIN TableB ON TableA.Email = TableB.Email
WHERE TableA.NID <> TableB.NID
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM TableA A FULL OUTER JOIN
     TableB B ON A.Email = B.Email
             AND A.NID <> B.NID
;
```

It's not clear if you want only the `A` records, only the `B` records, or both. You'd change the `SELECT` and `JOIN` type depending on which data you're expecting back.

This solves the question as you described it, but if you run it against tables containing your sample data you're going to get an empty result set.